# Splitting a square into equal areas

Tags: geometry

I am looking to split a square into 4 **equal** areas, not necessarily needing to be the same shapes or sizes . I need to find a way to use the least length of lines ( which could be straight or curved lines) inside the square to split and divide it up. What would be the optimal solution. I need to code an algorithm to do it too but I wanted to understand the mathematical concept behind it first. Also how would I use this for a rectangle say side height 1 and length 2.

Comment: I can't imagine it would be anything different than $\boxplus$... I don't have a proof in mind, but its obvious that it uses less length than $\boxtimes$.

Comment: It could also be something similar to what happens with [minimum surface area](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0Xv_9wRVrs) where the shapes get more involved and exotic... but using these sort of minimum surface tension with soap films wouldn't respect the requirement that the regions be of equal area.

Comment: Yeah but the most obvious way is clearly not the most optimal.

Answer (score 4):

My calculations show that the obvious configuration is not quite optimal.
Consider the square  $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.  The division by straight horizontal and vertical lines has total length $2$.  Let $\alpha$ be the root of the polynomial $768 z^8 + 64 z^6 - 72 z^4 + 1$ approximately $0.4694760731$, and
$\beta = 1/(4\alpha)$.
Partition the square using the points $[\alpha,\alpha]$, $[1-\alpha,1-\alpha]$,
$[0,\beta]$, $[\beta,0]$, $[1,1-\beta]$, $[1-\beta,1]$, looking like this:

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, this has equal areas and total length $4 \sqrt{\alpha^2 + (\alpha - \beta)^2} + \sqrt{2} (1-2\alpha) \approx 1.981089021 < 2$.

I'm not claiming that this is optimal, either.  You should do better by replacing the four straight line segments touching the boundary with circular arcs.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, actually!  I needed to be quicker from lunch :-S +1.

Comment: How would I do it for circular arcs though please.

Comment: Also would it be the exact same for a shape like a rectangle. Say height 1 and length 2.

Comment: Also how did you get that polynomial ?

Comment: Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The given polynomial has another real root, i.e. $\alpha=0.38450091314$. Can we use that too to get another splitting?